# Obtener indices (repetidos) de filas con pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Uso VS Code en windows. Explico el problema. Tengo un DF y quiero contar la cantidad de veces que se repite un valor determinado. Ejemplo del DF:

```
fecha       col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8    col9    col10   col11   col12   col13   col14   col15   col16   col17   col18   col19   col20
17/2/2022   06  19  86  34  08  88  34  96  58  51  97  15  98  15  29  37  87  20  86  19
18/2/2022   77  89  64  86  88  89  69  26  99  60  76  44  65  50  72  94  33  14  31  73
19/2/2022   35  43  83  64  04  74  60  78  83  32  70  15  27  73  52  88  99  39  38  06
20/2/2022   30  18  09  20  27  44  70  59  56  08  85  71  79  19  84  36  05  59  49  68
21/2/2022   02  08  00  91  98  64  37  94  35  14  89  18  22  78  56  48  29  19  85  75
```

El problema viene cuando necesito saber cuantas veces se repite. Dejo el codigo de ejemplo.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("numeros.csv", header=0)
valor = 64
print(df.index[(df["col1"] == valor) |(df["col2"] == valor) |(df["col3"] == valor) |(df["col4"] == valor) |
     (df["col5"] == valor) |(df["col6"] == valor) |(df["col7"] == valor) |(df["col8"] == valor) |
     (df["col9"] == valor) |(df["col10"] == valor) |(df["col11"] == valor) |(df["col12"] == valor) |
     (df["col13"] == valor) |(df["col14"] == valor) |(df["col15"] == valor) |(df["col16"] == valor) |
     (df["col17"] == valor) |(df["col18"] == valor) |(df["col19"] == valor) |(df["col20"] == valor)].tolist())
```

Produccion

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

Pero si, por ejemplo, la variable es de 19 obtengo:

```
[0, 3, 4]
```

Y lo que necesito es:

```
[0, 0, 3, 4]
```

Cuando uso index[blabla].tolist() no me figuran las veces que se repite un numero en esa fila. Podria agregarlo con Append pero no se como buscar ese valor repetido en la fila, aun sabiendo el numero del indice.
Estoy aprendiendo Pyhton y se que no empecé por el principio. Me basta con que me digan "investiga tal funcion o parametro". Probe varias cosas pero no logro dar con lo que quiero.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Investiga como agrupar un Dataframe usando el metodo groupby c:

Comment: Aquí te dejo links de la documentación del método [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), el cual devuelve un objeto especial llamado [DataFrameGroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html)

Comment: @DanteS., estuve pensando un buen rato y no se me ocurrió como resolverlo con `groupby` tal vez puedas mostrar una respuesta para calmar mi curiosidad haha.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato creo que malinterprete la pregunta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

En primer lugar, hay una forma más fácil de obtener el filtro que deseas en lugar de comparar cada columna. En lugar de hacer esto:

```
(df["col1"] == valor) |(df["col2"] == valor) |(df["col3"] == valor) |(df["col4"] == valor) |
(df["col5"] == valor) |(df["col6"] == valor) |(df["col7"] == valor) |(df["col8"] == valor) |
(df["col9"] == valor) |(df["col10"] == valor) |(df["col11"] == valor) |(df["col12"] == valor) |
(df["col13"] == valor) |(df["col14"] == valor) |(df["col15"] == valor) |(df["col16"] == valor) |
(df["col17"] == valor) |(df["col18"] == valor) |(df["col19"] == valor) |(df["col20"] == valor)
```

Puedes utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), esto ahorra código y además funciona más rápido al no tener que comparar cada columna de forma independiente (Aunque quizás internamente siga comparando columna por columna como el código está en `C` y optimizado para `pandas` se ejecutará más rápido en un `dataframe` mucho más grande).

```
df.eq(valor)
```

El segundo punto es identificar el número de veces que existe el valor buscado en cada fila. La línea anterior devuelve un `dataframe` de booleanos indicando con `True` la celda donde está el valor buscado y cualquier otro valor será `False` por lo que únicamente tenemos que contar los `True` de cada fila para saber el número de veces que aparece el valor buscado por fila.

Si utilizamos [`pandas.DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) combinado con la igualación anterior vamos a poder saber el número de veces que se encuentra el valor buscado en cada fila.

```
df.eq(valor).sum(1)
```

Si buscáramos `valor = 19` entonces obtendríamos lo siguiente de la línea anterior:

```
0    2
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
dtype: int64
```

### Ahora viene la magia

Sabiendo el número de veces que se repite el valor en cada fila podemos crear una lista de índices al hacer que el valor del índice se repita el número de veces que se encontró el valor en cada fila. Utilizando el ejemplo anterior donde valor era `19` tendríamos que repetir el índice `0` dos veces, omitir los índices `1` y `2` y repetir los índices `3` y `4` una vez cada uno.

La forma más fácil y óptima de hacerlo es utilizando `numpy`, en específico, la función [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
print(np.repeat(df.index.values, df.eq(valor).sum(1)))
```

Ejemplo completo (Utilizando tu `dataframe` desde un archivo "sample.csv"):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

valor = 19

print(np.repeat(df.index.values, df.eq(valor).sum(1)))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
[0 0 3 4]
```

**Nota:** el resultado es un `array` (Arreglo) de `numpy`.

Comment: El resultado es excatamente lo que buscaba. Me tengo que poner a leer la documentacion de numpy. Mil gracias, amigo.

Comment: Buen día @MarianoToranzos, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Listo. No sabia que tenia que clickear en el tilde. De paso te agradezco por segunda vez. La he probado y me ahorro muchas lineas de codigo inservibles.